# How to secure RStudio server by fail2ban?

Tags: security, brute-force, rstudio-server, fail2ban

I have installed a RStudio server which allows for online login and programming from within the browser. Someone, having experience on how to secure the server by fail2ban?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It showed up being quite complicated to solve the protection of RStudio by fail2ban as RStudio does not log client IP's of failed login attempts.

However, instead [pam-abl](http://pam-abl.sourceforge.net) is a similar solution that protects against brute force attacks by blacklisting users and IP's after specified number of failed login attempts. This library is faster than fail2ban but it does not by default integrate with firewall, which would be a customization.